# TensorFlow optimizer one at a time or batch

Tags: tensorflow

The examples I've seen for TensorFlow optimizer have included code like the following:

```
pred = tf.tensordot(x, w, 1) + b
cost = tf.reduce_sum((pred-y)**2 / n_samples)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

...

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for (x1, y1) in zip(train_x, train_y):
        optimizer.run({x: x1, y: y1})
```

That incurs the overhead of a Python loop iteration for each training case. I decided to try it this way instead:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    optimizer.run({x: train_x, y: train_y})
```

And it seems to work equally well, and presumably faster.

Is there some reason I'm not aware of for doing it the one at a time way? Or is it indeed the case that the batch way should be used instead because it's a free speedup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first variant is optimising separately on each data pair. That is stochastic gradient descent with batch size 1. This is very likely slow since it it forgives any possibility for vector computation, e.g. if you use a GPU.

Your second variant is using the whole data set in each step, so it is true (not stochastic) gradient descent. This is unpractical for huge data sets and many authors say it is also slower in convergence.

A good compromise is mini-batching with a batch size larger 1, but much smaller than the total data set. You could start with a value of 100. On would expect a better convergence than both other approaches.

In tensor flow mini-batching is supported via the following call:
    https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch
This supports splitting your data in sequences of the desired size (e.g. 100).